# Show Alert only one time till next new coordinate

Tags: ios, swift

I am try to show alert if the distance larger than 200 meters. I found every time when I back to that page, alert show again, but the coordinate is not changed. For example, my app has two view controllers, one is mapkit, and another one is location history. When I go to the mapkit view that alert shows up, which is good, then I go to location history page and back to mapkit page, the alert shows again, but the coordinate is not updated yet. So, I wonder how to show alert only one time with same coordinate. And let alert shows up again with the new coordinate appear and distance larger than 200m. My code is shown below and it is under `viewDidLoad`. `coordinate0` is user current location and `coordinate1` is retrieved from firebase realtime database.

```
self.createAnnotation(locations: [annotationLocations])
let coordinate0 = CLLocation(latitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: Latitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: Longtitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
let distance = coordinate0.distance(from: coordinate1)

if (distance <= 200) {
    print(distance)
} else {
    self.creatAlert(title: "Is it you?", message: "Hi")
}
```

And my alert function code is shown below.

```
func creatAlert (title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Yes")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("No")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: can you provide extra info about the problem? did you use viewDidAppear for any location update? and also can you print the coordinate0 and coordinate1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `Latitude` and `Longitude` with the current location each time you show the alert. This way you always compare the current location with the last location that triggered the last alert.

As a side note, why not save off the location as a `CLLocation` instead of two separate variables? And name variable starting with lowercase.

```
self.createAnnotation(locations: [annotationLocations])
let coordinate0 = CLLocation(latitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: Latitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: Longtitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
let distance = coordinate0.distance(from: coordinate1)

if (distance <= 200) {
    print(distance)
} else {
    Latitude = coordinate0.coordinate.latitude
    Longitude = coordinate0.coordinate.longitude
    self.creatAlert(title: "Is it you?", message: "Hi")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am new in this field. Could you tell me how to modify code to avoid this problem? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @maddy I still don't know how to fix it. I am very new in this field. Could you show me how to fix it?

Comment: I updated my answer with the simple change you need. I don't know the actual data type you are using for `Latitude` and `Longitude` so you may get an error due to mismatched data types. But that should be simple enough for you to fix.